# How to make multiple images (and buttons) dissapear while pressing a button

Tags: image, button, roblox, luau

Im trying to make an roblox game, and i wanna make an action (which is the images & buttons dissapearing while you press a button. I am an rookie scripter, so how do i make it happen, with scripts? My explorer tab is positioned like this:

```
> StarterGui
>> GUI (a ScreenGui)
>>> PlayButton (a ImageButton)
>>> CreditButton (a TextButton)
>>> Background (a ImageLabel, but dont remove it)
>>> Title (another ImageLabel)
>>> TextLabel
```

I tried following guides, but nothing worked, and it resulted in nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local script inside one of the GUI buttons. Make it look something along the lines of:

```
local button = script.Parent
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
  local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
  player.PlayerGui.(Whatever GUI you want to hide).Transparency = 1 --Repeat this for as many GUI instances you want to hide, or use a for loop.
  player.PlayerGui.(GUI name).Active = false
end)
```